# Change dynamically the stylesheet depending on document mode

Tags: stylesheet, xpages

is there a way to change stylesheet file dynamically depending on if the document is in edit or read mode?

What I would like to do is to add the following code to the "compute value" option of the resource href property:

```
if(document.isEditable()){
   return "style_edit.css"
}
else{
   return "style_read.css"
}
```

My main problem with this is that when the page loads, it gives the error "document not found". This is probably because when the page loads, there is only a view that includes the documents and when the user clicks a document id, then the custom control with the binded document appears. I don't know how to make the binded to custom control document available on load of the page.

Edited:
I tried a try/catch block and now the xpage opens without displaying an error. But although the custom control is refreshed, the css file does not change, althoug I use compute dynamically and not compute on load

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can try using xpages themes, in xpages theme you can use SSJS and load CSS dynamically based on condition, check out team room db theme for ref

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, but at the moment I am not using any theme and I feel that this way will lead to more changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the resource `href` attribute as computed. For this go to All Properties of XPage "**basics > resources > styleSheet**". Here you can compute the `href` attribute with your JavaScript code. So your resource in XPage source would look something like this

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:this.href><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (document.isEditable()) {
    return "style_edit.css";
} else {
    return "style_read.css";
}}]]></xp:this.href>
    </xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
```

To access the data source from custom control you can use the global variable `currentDocument` instead of `document`.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to do, but on page loading it gives the error "currentDocument not found". This is probably because when the page loads, there is only a view that includes the documents and when the user clicks a document id, then the  custom control with the binded document appears. I don't know how to make the binded to custom control document available on load of the page

Comment: @kmak: Have you tried to surround the SSJS code with a try/catch-block?

Comment: @kmak: Can you please clarify/edit your question because in it you are asking _What I would like to do is to add the following code to the "compute value" option of the resource href..._ based on which I answered you?

Comment: @SvenHasselbach I tried a try/catch block and now the xpages opens without displaying an error. But although the custom control is refreshed, the css file does not change, althoug I use compute dynamically and not compute on load.

Answer (score 2):

Why force user to download separate files on edition when You can simply add computed styleClass to some panel/component:

```
<xp:panel>
        <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:return document.isEditable()?"docEditMode":"docReadMode";}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
</xp:panel>
```

and use it as a selector inside style.css

Comment: +1 it is better idea to keep single CSS with proper selectors to handle document mode

Comment: Yes this is how I accomplish it at the moment. You are probably right about it. The thing that made me think about separate css files is that if another programmer want to make changes, he/she will have to change every single panel or component. But if I understand well, you are saying that this is preferable to using separate files.